# options to extend an interface with one different value without having to re-write that object?

Tags: typescript

What is the best approach to make a similar interface that is different in only one value, then to duplicate code and rewrite the object again ? Could this be done without union type ?

```
// A1
export interface FirstType {
  id: string;
  parentId: string;
  type: 'a1';
  data : string[]
  dataA : string[]
  dataB : string[]
  dataC : string[]
  dataD : string[]
  dataE : string[]
}

// A2
export interface SecondType extends FirstType {
   type: 'a2';
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a union? Is it some sort of a requirement, or is it just because the `type: 'a1'` conflicts?

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes it is a payload function that has it's own if block and union will cause an issue, yet both types are identical.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Is it that the `type: 'a1'` is incompatible, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [the `Omit<T, K>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to produce a named type suitable for [interface extension](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types):

```
export interface SecondType extends Omit<FirstType, "type"> {
    type: 'a2';
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQSgGcYAVATzDwG8AoORxAEwC45SpkBzAbgaZhMUYCgCSbDjC5I+AxjCrB2AckwBGFfyZxmmGJnaceAbQC683fswBBI9NMWdegwCF7M7ucsvMAYQ9HH2sAEUDZb2drAFFwrwsAXzpk0EhYRBQ0LFw4AGVgbAgkZkpqOFBUYuI4AHkAWwQYAB5CEnIlABo4ACJFam6APjh6HT7lODUAJi06BKA)

Comment: so technically you extend and remove the different value, great clean approach..... works like charm.